# Use only Gnome on Elementary OS

Tags: pantheon, gnome

So I want to use only vanilla gnome with Elementary OS as I am more at ease working with that.

However,(I am using Freya) I cannot seem to find a solution for implementing this.

How should I replace Pantheon with Gnome.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because why would you do this instead of installing ubuntu gnome?? Might as well shoot yourself on the foot.

Answer (score 2):

why not use [ubuntu gnome](https://ubuntugnome.org/) directly than elementary?

The problem is that you can't use the latest version of gnome and keep pantheon and other elementary apps, this is because the gtk version used in both desktops are diferents, pantheon uses gtk 3.14 and the latest version of gnome use gtk 3.20, so if you install one the other broke.

Any way if you still want to try to install gnome just run this two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

this will install gnome 3.14 to your pc.

Comment: Well, my problem with Ubuntu is that I cannot get my drivers to work properly with it. (I expected the same problem with Elementary, but inexplicably it worked. And I see that the desktop-shell which comes with Elementary has it's own share of bugs (compatibility with 3rd-party apps like nemo, synapse-indicator, battery-indicator freeze). It's not too much of a problem, but I would definitely like to switch to Gnome if possible. You mentioned breaking of the shell, I don't understand. I do not want to use them concurrently. I want to remove Pantheon and install Gnome Shell(vanilla).

Comment: just try with:
"sudo apt-get purge elementary-desktop"
to remove pantheon and then use this 2 commands
"sudo apt-get install gnome-shell"
"sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop" and you will have gnome 3.14 installed

Comment: nope doesn't work: there are dependencies which cannot be solved...

Comment: can you post some info about  the dependencies problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`

`sudo apt install -y ubuntu-desktop gnome gnome-shell`